# How to write a query like SQL's SELECT x FROM 

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7, gql

I want to write a query that does something like this SQL query:

```
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE blah blah
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
for contact in Contacts.gql(WHERE_CLAUSE, args).fetch(1000):
  print contact.name
```

but isn't there a way to get `name` directly from a query without having to loop on the results? would it provide any advantage in performance?

Comment: You can fetch either only keys or full entities. Only-keys-fetch gives great performance advantage. If your name is unique, you could use it as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Can't be done.

> A GQL query returns zero or more entities or Keys of the requested
>   kind. Every GQL query always begins with either SELECT * or SELECT
>   **key**. (A GQL query cannot perform a SQL-like "join" query.)

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

But you can create a simple wrapper to do it for you. Something like:

```
def get_all_of_field(model, field):
  for x in model.all():
    yield getattr(x, field)

names = get_all_of_field(Contact, 'name')
```

Performance can't be improved that way as the entire "line" is read by the API no matter what. Either you read the entire "line" or just its key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now using Projection queries. For db, see the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries

For ndb, see the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection